# How to build and install libvirt on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, installation, libvirt

I referred to [this article](http://lsimons.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/libvirt-vmware-fusion-mac-os-x/), but used more recent libraries. To be explicit, I downloaded 
`libgpg-error-1.10`, `libgcrypt-1.5.0`,`gnutls-3.1.3` and `libvirt-1.0.0`

`libgpg-error-1.10`, `libgcrypt-1.5.0` installed OK and when configure `gnutls-3.1.3`, an error comes:

> configure: error:
>
> *** Libnettle 2.5 was not found. Note that you must compile nettle with gmp support.

What I want is to use libvirt's python binding(i.e. `import libvirt` in python). Could anyone explain how to get a useable python libvirt library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your easiest options is probably using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install `libvirt`:

```
$ brew install libvirt
```

After that compiling the Python bindings for `libvirt` should be trivial.

Comment: libvirt python bindings are compiled automatically, but need to be linked under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` from `/usr/local/Cellar/libvirt/0.9.11.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` manually

Answer (score 7):

After you install libvirt with:

`$ brew install libvirt`

you can install the libvirt python bindings with pip:

`$ pip install libvirt-python`

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following commands on a fairly fresh MacOSX 10.10.5

```
bash-3.2$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
bash-3.2$ brew install libvirt
bash-3.2$ brew install libvirt-python
bash-3.2$ pip install libvirt-python
bash-3.2$ echo Instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136884/how-to-build-and-install-libvirt-on-mac do not work.

bash-3.2$ sudo easy_install pip
bash-3.2$ pip install libvirt-python
bash-3.2$ echo typical python stuff up - when the install of a tool gets in your way - toss the tool
bash-3.2$ echo unless the tool has worked many many times before.
bash-3.2$ pip install pkg-config
bash-3.2$ brew install pkg-config
bash-3.2$ pip install libvirt-python
bash-3.2$ sudo pip install libvirt-python
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrews solution works with one modification for `El Capitan` and up. As theses versions do not allow write access to `/usr/share` you need to provide `pkg-config` with the path of the `libvirt api`, something like:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libvirt/4.3.0/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: Which solution are you referring to?